# Passing IBOutlet/object into generic function for repeatable animations

Tags: ios, swift, generics, uiview

I am writing an app that utilizes the same animation on multiple elements. To make my life easier, I want to create a generic function that will take in an object from my storyboard and animate it.

What I'm looking for

```
// Object I want to pass
IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

// Animate function
func animateIn<T>(a: AnyObject, myType:T.Type) {
    if let a = a as? T{
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
            a.transform = .identity
        })

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.1, options: [], animations: {
            a.alpha = 1.0
        })
    }
}

// Call function
animateIn(a: titleLabel, myType: UILabel.self)
```

However, I get the errors:

> Value of type `T` has no member `transform`
>   Value of type `T` has no member `alpha`

How can I fix this?

Comment: You are not even using anything different than UIView, just make the type UIView, not sure why need generic with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *really* want to design this as a generic function — more on this later — then you must *constraint* the generic parameter `T` as a `UIView` subclass. For instance:

```
func animateIn<T: UIView>(view: T) {
    UIView.animate(...) {
        view.transform = ...
    }
}
```

usage:

```
animateIn(view: titleLabel)
```

And, in doing so, you really don’t need that extra metatype parameter of yours (i.e., `myType: T.Type`). The correctly constrained generic `T` is all you need ;)

**Non-generic alternative**. If your `animate` function won’t be accepting any other related views parameters (and won’t be returning any views as well) you might be better off skipping generics altogether for such a simple function:

```
func animateIn(view: UIView) {
    ...
}
```